# VS 2012 / 2013 AccessViolationException

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

When I run the project (F5) I receive the following exception in IDE:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Stack trace reports

```
at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(Int32 msg, Int32 wparam, IntPtr lparam)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.UpdateWindowIcon(Boolean redrawFrame)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.CreateHandle()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunParkingWindowThread()
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

I have never noticed receiving the same exception when running without debugger (CTRL+F5). This is a WPF project, but exception occurs before the App_ctor is executed, so this is external code, and my application code did not start to execute. This happens sporadically, sometimes it happens only once, and sometimes I run the project and get this message for several times in a roll. Then it does not pop up for 5-6 runs, and then starts again.

Anyone knows why is this happening? I have just installed clean W8.1 64 bit, VS2013 and TFS 2013 (although I had the same problem with W8 and VS2012, but not as often).

Comment: [see also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24497835/accessviolationexception-while-stepping-through-c-code-in-visual-studio-2013-up) which has a comment including a work around

Comment: I've been playing with this, and here's what I found:  It only happens when the method is an override AND the structure contains more than one member, And at least one of those is NOT Int16, Int32, UInt16, UInt32, Single or Boolean.  That doesn't answer "why" but does offer some evidence.  VS 12.0.31101.00 Update 4 on Win7/64

Answer (score 3):

This issue appears to be fixed in a dot net framework update (4.5.2).
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/819552/visual-studio-debugger-throws-accessviolationexception