# AccessViolationException while stepping through C#-Code in Visual Studio 2013 Update 2

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, access-violation

I think i've found a bug in the debugger in Visual Studio 2013 Update 2. When i derive from an abstract class and override an abstract method which accepts a struct with two strings, the debugging session crashes with an AccessViolationException.

This behaviour occours with 64 bit architecture and on .NET framework 4.0 and above (4.5 and 4.5.1).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new console project. Use Any CPU or x64 (this will only work on a 64 bit capable system!) and use .NET Framework 4.0, 4.5 or 4.5.1.
2. Copy & paste the code below.
3. Set a breakpoint on the first line of code in the Main-method.
4. Step through the code till the end.
5. AccessViolationException occours at the last line of the Main-method.

Now my questions:

1. Can anyone reproduce this behaviour?
2. How could this happen and how can i debug such errors better than with visual studio?
3. Where can i report this kind of errors?

Thank you for your time.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Structure structure = new Structure();

            Caller caller = new Caller();

            caller.Execute(structure);
        }
    }

    public abstract class Father
    {
        internal Father()
        {
        }

        public abstract bool Execute(Structure structure);
    }

    public class Caller : Father
    {
        public Caller() : base()
        {
        }

        public override bool Execute(Structure structure)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public struct Structure
    {
        public string A;
        public string B;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce using "AnyCPU" or "x64", using VS 2012 update 4, .net 4.5.1.

Comment: Reproducible here with VS2013 Express Windows Desktop (12.0.21005.1 REL), but only with x64 target (AnyCPU works). Target framework 4.5.1.

Comment: Thank you elgonzo, your suggestion worked also for me. Sorry for the duplicate. :(