# Getting a System.AccessViolationException only during debug

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5

**UPDATE**

I've changed the question with my latest findings and simplified as much as possible.

I have the following piece of code

```
public virtual int DefineAction(bool b, string s, Type1 t1, Type2 t2)
{
    return 1;
}

public ProcessResult Process(bool b, string s, Type1 t1, Type2 t2)
{
   int i = DefineAction(b, s, t1, t2);    
   // more code
}
```

When I put a breakpoint on the Line var `int i= ...`
and I try to step through it I get an `AccessVialoationExeption`

**UPDATE:** If I remove `virtual` for the function `DefineAction` no Exeption is thrown.

**UPDATE2:** If I remove one parameter from`DefineAction` for example define it as `DefineAction(bool b, string s, Type1 t1)` no Exeption is thrown.
It's freaking me out now :-(

None of the Assemblies is marked as unsafe. There's nothing running in separate threads.

If I run the program in Visual Studio in Debug mode without breakpoint, the Exeption is not throwing

Any hints or ideas how what's going wrong here?

Comment: It is unclear : is the exception is happening in debug, or not happening in debut ? Moreover, your code doesn't compile as such

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.accessviolationexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It would also be useful to see the `DefineAction` method or to know more about it (return type for example)

Comment: @MickaelV. the exeption happening in debug, when i put a breakpoint on the line. but no exeption happens if the breakpoint is not set. First line of define action is return null;

Comment: @MickaelV. updated the question with my last findings.

Comment: I think you need to think about (or show us) how you're using inheritance here

Comment: Also, if it happens only in debug, can you check if you're in that case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513384/weird-access-violation-exception ?

Comment: @MickaelV. thanks for the hint. it looks like the same issue (VS Bug)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this VS bug:
[Weird Access Violation Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513384/weird-access-violation-exception/24531722#comment44835793_24531722)

Reported here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/911564/access-violation-exception-in-vs-hosting-process-when-debugging-application

And assumingly fixed in this .NET release:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42642

Comment: Installed 4.5.2 (but still targeting 4.5.0) works smooth again as expected.

Comment: using .net core 2.0 on VS 2017. Same issue. No fix. Unlike .net framework 4.x.x. -> at this point there is nowhere to upgrade to. Latest version of VS and Core are installed.

Comment: If it's indeed the same issue, know that you can work around it by not stepping over the line of code (IRC issue was related to parameter evaluation in VS). I'd also report this to MS.