# Visual Studio 2013 Access Violation in debug mode

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ide, access-violation

I cannot debug my program in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate under Windows 10. When I try run project I get AccessViolationException. I ran VS as admin, created empty Console Application, set break point at the first line of my app and run debugging (F5) and I got [following message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPxr4.jpg).

I tried to run application without debugging and it worked, so I realized it is debugger problem. I tried to repair and reinstall Visual Studio and it does not work. I get this Exception in all projects, so I cannot debug. It happenes only with C# (everything is OK for C++ for example).

I founded similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578568/vs-2012-2013-accessviolationexception) but link from answer does not work.

I attached call stack [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1xBO.png)