# Not using Winforms but get an Access Violation Exception in Windows.Forms.dll at startup?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I'm having trouble with some weird exception in .NET. I get this exception randomly at startup (only when executing in Visual Studio), and when it occurs, it does not execute any user-specific code (coded by me). e.g., Breakpoints in `App.xaml` or in `MainWindow.xaml` are not hit, because the exception occurs earlier.

Should maybe mention, that it is a WPF application. Another interesting fact is, that I have not imported the Windows.Forms.dll (and therefore do not use it) in my project.

Attached: Stacktrace and Exception message.

Any idea why this exception occurs?
I would appreciate your help. Thanks!

**Exception**

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>   Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

**Stacktrace**

[image: Stacktrace]

Comment: Regarding to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578568/vs-2012-2013-accessviolationexception 
I just changed the .NET target framework from 4.5 to 4.6. and the problem seems to be solved. I'll keep an eye on that.
Edit: Unfortunately, problem still occurs.

Comment: It happens.  We can't see enough, you did not enable unmanaged code debugging.  Judging from what is there, you probably ought to go shopping for a different icon.  If you did not in fact change the Icon property of the form then you need the geek squad to fix your machine.