# Visual Studio 2015 - System.AccessViolationException

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I keep getting this error about ~15 minutes after my VB.net program runs.

It doesn't point to a particular line of code, the program is using a web browser where it's automating a process, reading data and then clicking elements within the browser.

I seen a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578568/vs-2012-2013-accessviolationexception), asking the same question but for Visual Stuidio 2012 / 2013, their solution was an 4.5.2 .NET update [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42642), but that update is already installed where I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

I'm using Windows 10. Program is over 2000 lines and it doesn't isolate any portion of code. After a lot of searching and deadends, this is my last resort, can somebody please help me?

[image]

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace from the exception?

Comment: HI Jake, I knew they would be some sort of output for the error, stack trace rings a bell. I'm running the program again and will post it once I see the error again. Really appreciate taking time out of your day for this my friend.